# How to get from Copenhagen airport to Odense (Denmark)?

Tags: trains, public-transport, airport-transfer, denmark, cph

I'm flying into CPH (Copenhagen Airport) and then need to get to Odense, Denmark via train. How do I navigate through CPH (Copenhagen Airport)to the central station to get the right train to Odense?

Answer (score 13):

The train station is located in terminal 3. From terminal 1 you can take a free shuttle bus to terminal 3.

There is a direct train to Odense every hour. Otherwise you can take one of the frequent trains to Copenhagen central station and change there for a train bound to Odense. The journey lasts a bit less than two hours.

Tickets can be bought at the ticket machines in terminal 3 just above the railway station. There is also a DSB ticket sales counter, located in terminal 3.

It's all straightforward. Just follow the signs.

For train schedules check http://www.dsb.dk